# html select box down arrow looks like mouse

Tags: html, css

On IE8,9 and 10 a select element looks like the attached picture.  The drop down arrow is replaced with something that looks more or less like a mouse.

On Firefox and Chrome it looks like a standard drop down with a down arrow.

I can't find anywhere that I've done anything with CSS to alter selects.

Any suggestions?

```
  <td>
    <select id='allocated' name='alloc' onchange='allocChange()'>
    <option value='??' selected='selected'>??</option>
    <option value='1A' >1A</option>
    <option value='1B' >1B</option>
    <option value='1C' >1C</option>
    <option value='2A' >2A</option>
    <option value='2B' >2B</option>
    <option value='3A' >3A</option>
    </select>
  </td>
```

CSS not a factor - same thing happens even when stylesheet not loaded

[image]

Comment: please share some code .

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h6Kg5/ If you check here for me the select looks default, If you still see it your own way then it's something wrong with you're system. Good luck!

Comment: i'm sorry but this is extremely funny. yet another way for IE to mess with your life

Comment: Thanks for the jsFiddle Axente - I don't know why I didn't think to try that myself.  The dropdown looks exactly the same in the JsFiddle as it does in my application.  I've reset EI to default settings, tried different desktop themes.....  Nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 0):

It may be by default.. But you can change the arrow using css

```
.styleSelect select {
background: transparent;
width: 168px;
padding: 5px;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1;
border: 0;
border-radius: 0;
height: 34px;
-webkit-appearance: none;
color: #000;
}

.styleSelect {
width: 140px;
height: 34px;
overflow: hidden;
background: url("images/downArrow.png") no-repeat right #fff;
border: 2px solid #000;
}
```